# Regex - How do I replace only part of a string?

Tags: regex

I have this so far:

```
(?<="rec_rec_three": ").*(?=")
```

Which when applied to

```
"rec_rec_three": "tini-bikini-martini"
```

gives me

```
tini-bikini-martini
```

but my goal is to replace all -'s with _'s ...  how do I accomplish it?

Comment: Messing with JSON? :) What is your regex flavor? Try [`(?:"rec_rec_three":\s*"|(?!^)\G)\K([^"-]*)-`](https://regex101.com/r/pN8rU6/1) replacing with `$1_`.

Comment: What is your goal? To replace the _value_ part `-` characters with `_` ?

Comment: The fastest and easiest way is to just match `("rec_rec_three":\s*")([^"]+)(?=")` use a callback joining capture group 1 with a normal string replace of `-` with `_` from capture group 2. If you have the `\K` construct in your engine, you could ignore the groups  entirely.`"rec_rec_three":\s*"\K[^"]+(?=")`. But using anything with this scenario `(?<=....).*(?=..)` could cause backtracking problems if the trailing literal is not found.

Comment: Why not do `replace("-", "_")`, or your language's equivalent?  Either this is a no-brainer, or you're leaving something out.

Answer (score 0):

If your regexp flavor supports \K and \G, it's easy to do such a substitute using an expression like

```
's/(\G|"rec_rec_three": ")[^"]*?\K-/_/g
```

`\G` means a reference to the previous match end, and `\K` sets the effective beginning of the current match to the position where it occurs.
Note that (at least in Perl) this should be the first match operation on a given string variable. Otherwise, \G may be inherited from that previous one. (See http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html for details)

A simple test:

```
> cat testfile
"rec_rec_three": "tini-bikini-martini"
"rec_rec_one": "tini-bikini-martini" "rec_rec_two": "tini-bikini-martini" "rec_rec_three": "tini-bikini-martini" "rec_rec_four": "tini-bikini-martini"

> cat testfile |   perl -n -e 's/(\G|"rec_rec_three": ")[^"]*?\K-/_/g;print'
"rec_rec_three": "tini_bikini_martini"
"rec_rec_one": "tini-bikini-martini" "rec_rec_two": "tini-bikini-martini" "rec_rec_three": "tini_bikini_martini" "rec_rec_four": "tini-bikini-martini"
```